# Apache - How to use .htaccess to rewrite index.html?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm with some trouble to rewrite .htaccess in this scenario: I'm rewriting the index.hml to /some-example-uri/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^some-example-uri/$ index.html [NC]
```

And this actually works. But now I need to redirect all the requests from mydomain.com to mydomain.com/some-example-uri/

Can someone give me a clue on how to do this?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> from mydomain.com to mydomain.com/some-example-uri/

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /some-example-uri [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It works, but it is not doing the redirect. I need that a request to mydomain.com redirect to mydomain.com/some-example-uri/